# r - aligning x-axis image and base plot

Tags: r, image, plot

When I try to align an image plot with a xy plot by their x-axis there is a small misalignment between the x-values. Can't figure out how to get rid of it!
Notice the misalignment of the vertical lines from the bottom plot with the x-axis on the top plot.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar=c(0,5,5,5))
image(x=1:100,z=replicate(10, rnorm(100)))
par(mar=c(5,5,0,5))
par(xaxs="i")
plot(1:100,rnorm(100))
abline(v=1:100)
```

Gurus, help!! Thank you!!

PS: Could not figure it out with the post "plot-time-series-and-image-in-r-so-that-x-axis-labels-line-up-perfectly", still having issues!

Comment: do you want to get rid of the x-axis belonging to the upper plot?

Comment: Nope, I want to align both x-axes perfectly. If you notice they do not fully align. I left the x-axis on the top plot to make the misalignment more evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `image` draws data as a grid of cells which have a given width. If the length of `x` in `image` equals to `nrow(z)` then it specifies the midpoints of the cells. In your example this gives you rectangles centered around 1:100, effectively resulting in the x-axis covering the range from `0.5` to `100.5`, which gives the observed misalignment.

In order to match the ranges in both plots you need to specify `xlim` to `plot` accordingly. In the following example I use `n = 10` to make things more obvious.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar=c(0,5,5,5))
image(x=1:n,z=replicate(10, rnorm(n)))
par(mar=c(5,5,0,5))
par(xaxs="i")
plot(1:n,rnorm(n), xlim=c(.5,n+.5))
abline(v=1:n)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!! Nice! I thought it had to do with the cell width but did not figure out a way around it. Very useful indeed, thank you very much!

Comment: As a general solution for a given vector of values time.vec and step time.step I did xlim=c(time.vec[1] - (0.5 * time.step), max(time.vec) + (0.5 * time.step))

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is one of those things I had probably figured out on the past and then completely forgot about.
The trick is not only calling par(xaxs="i") but also enforcing both xlims!

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar=c(0,5,5,5))
image(x=1:100,z=replicate(10, rnorm(100)),xlim=c(0,100))
par(mar=c(5,5,0,5))
par(xaxs="i")
plot(1:100,rnorm(100),xlim=c(0,100))
abline(v=1:100)
```

Comment: You got it right with `xlim`! But even though your solution brings both axes in sync, it doesn't properly account for the width of the grid, see also my answer. It cuts the rightmost column in half, and leaves a blank column on the left; you can see it better if you make a plot for a smaller range, say `1:10`.